# How do I say " One more" in Ancient Greek?

Tags: ancient-greek, english-to-greek-translation

How would I say "one more" (as in, "one more beer") in Ancient Greek. My friends and I have an inside joke of always saying "one more" whenever someone wants to leave a party or go home early from hanging out.

And our friend is really into Ancient Greek so we want to make him a gift and we need to write this for him.

Thank you.

Comment: What is "one" referring to? Ancient Greek has grammatical gender, so the form will depend on what word is implied

Comment: @TKR "one" as in beer. (I'm the one who asked the question, I'm still new here... Thanks!)

Comment: @Vuk Please see [these instructions for merging your registered account with the unregistered one that owns this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). That will give you better access to things like writing comments and marking an answer as accepted when you get a good one.

Answer (score 3):

An idiomatic way to put it would be:

> ἔτι ἄλλο

Or if you want all caps:

> ΕΤΙ ΑΛΛΟ

This literally means "yet another". I've used the neuter form ἄλλο to imply some neuter noun such as πῶμα "drink".

Comment: Apparently ζῦθος has some attestations for "beer" in ancient Greek.

Comment: @brianpck True, but I avoided that because I'm not sure it could be treated as a count noun.