# Four more loaves please

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

This new question: [How do I say " One more" in Ancient Greek?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/23408/1982), reminded me of an old question: [How do you say "one more [something]"?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/14365/1982), in which cnread advised that an ablative (in Latin) is used to indicate the degree of difference e.g, "one more apple" would be "more apples by one". An example: "una (ablative) plures tribus"--"one more tribe".

Beyond three, numbers are no longer governed by grammatical rules; therefore, the ablative cannot be deployed. How to say:

> "Four more loaves than yesterday, please,"

My guess, in 2020, was:

> "quattuor plures panes (quam) heri, si audes,".

Is this correct?

There could have been more serious implications to this e.g. what if a Roman officer had wanted to say:

> "I want/need a 1000 more soldiers, please!"

Apart from the assumption that he would not have bothered with, "please", what would a Tribunus have said?

Comment: The question asking about I want/need a 1000 more soliders, struck a chord in me with "Give me back my legions' or in the Latin from a google search  'Quintili Vare, legiones redde. So if has the authority, perhaps not as the request "I want" but perhaps as the command give me? da (do, dare).

Answer (score 2):

In Nicholas Oulton's Book II, p.50: "plures copias cupit"--"He wants more forces,".

The Tribunus would have said:

> "plures copias cupio (mille milites), si audes!"

Alternatively, "copias" could be omitted given that "mille"--"one thousand" is an indeclinable adjective and "milites" can be the accusative plural, giving:

> "I want a 1,000 more soldiers, please!"

(My Tribunus is polite, even if the real ones were not.)

Note: when "a thousand" goes into the plural, "milia", is a neuter noun which does decline.

As for the grocery shop:

> "plures panes cupio (quattuor), (quam) heri, si audes."

As already mentioned, "quattour" is indeclinable.